# Add new image block, set default class name and update it using Javascript

Tags: custom-field, images, javascript, advanced-custom-fields, block-editor

I am trying to programmatically set a default class on an image block, which is applied without the user manually adding it via the 'Additional CSS' field.

I have tried applying a default style on image blocks, which works initially -

```
wp.blocks.registerBlockStyle( 'core/image', {
  name: 'retailResidential',
  label: 'Retail & Residential',
  isDefault: true
});
```

But after it is initialized, unregistering the block style, then registering a new default block style has no effect for additionally created images (does not create an image with the updated default style, still uses the old).

```
wp.blocks.unregisterBlockStyle(
  'core/image',
  [ 'retailResidential', 'weddingsEvents', 'advertisingEditorial']
);
```

Does the editor need to be refreshed? or is there a better way of doing this?